# I need to know the window handle from the presentation model

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I know its an anti pattern to have WPF specific connections to the presentation model.
But in this case i cant avoide it (I use SLIM DX for joystick input and it requires the handle).

So is there a way from the presenation model to get the handle of the window connected to the model?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, if your view model is inherited from Screen you can call GetView, cast it to the type of your view, and get access to a control on the view.

```
var myView = GetView() as OrderView;
myView.SlimDX ...
```

An alternative if you don't want to reference your view from the VM it might be possible to do what you need in a coroutine.

"It’s a fairly simple interface to implement. Simply write your code in the “Execute” method and be sure to raise the “Completed” event when you are done, whether it be a synchronous or an asynchronous task. Because coroutines occur inside of an Action, we provide you with an ActionExecutionContext useful in building UI-related IResult implementations. This allows the ViewModel a way to declaratively state it intentions in controlling the view without having any reference to a View or the need for interaction-based unit testing. Here’s what the ActionResultContext looks like:"

```
public class ActionExecutionContext
{
    public ActionMessage Message;
    public FrameworkElement Source;
    public object EventArgs;
    public object Target;
    public DependencyObject View;
    public MethodInfo Method;
    public Func<bool> CanExecute;
    public object this[string key];
}
```

http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=IResult%20and%20Coroutines&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: Thanks will check that out, yeah i knew about the GetView method, but I didn't want that coupling.

Answer (score 0):

You have the two choices above, but also keep in mind the Handle is not set until 
OnViewLoaded is fired so make sure that you read the handle after this.